# Initializing and Cleanup in Singleton Class

Tags: c++, oop, singleton

I have a singleton  class like this :

**myClass.h**

```
class myClass
{


private:

    static myClass *singleton;
    myClass ( myClass const& );
    myClass& operator = ( myClass const& );
    myClass (  );


public:

    static myClass* Instance (  );
    ~myClass (  );
};
```

**myClass.cpp**

```
myClass::myClass (  ) {  };

myClass* myClass::singleton = NULL;

myClass* myClass::Instance (  )
{

    if ( !singleton )
    {

        singleton = new myClass;

        // Initialization

    }

    return singleton;

};


myClass::~myClass ( ) 
{

   // Cleanup           

};
```

Now I need to do some initialization before the object instance is returned and some cleanup in the destructor. Since myClass* myClass::Instance (  ) is a static function I can not access member variables from it, and I can't have those variables as static too.

So how do I achieve it ?

Comment: I am no C++ expert, but can't you do `singleton.member = new whatever;` after you have called the constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overload your `myClass::Instance` to either take arguments or none and overload your `private` constructor:

```
private:

   myClass();
   myClass(string);

....

public:

//Pass a value to your singleton object

myClass* myClass::Instance(string str)
{

    if ( !singleton )
    {

        singleton = new myClass(str); //overload private constructor and pass values

        // Initialization

    }

    return singleton;
}

//pass no value to singleton object

myClass* myClass::Instance()
{

    if ( !singleton )
    {

        singleton = new myClass(); //overload private constructor
        // Initialization

    }

    return singleton;
}
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something very basic :(